# AngularJS ui-router not rendering state template occasionally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Experiencing a very strange issue within our AngularJs app using ui-router. We have the following nested state structure...

holder.html

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

checkout/index.html - with nested ui-views(one named)

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="checkout.reviewLayoutEnabled ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-8'">

      <div class="row">
          <div ui-view="progress"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" style="position:relative;">
        <div ui-view="" class="page-fade"></div>
      </div>

   </div>
```

This is how it should be come together in the browser...

```
<!--holder.html-->
<div ui-view>


   <!--checkout/index.html-->
   <div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="checkout.reviewLayoutEnabled ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-8'">

      <div class="row">
          <div ui-view="progress"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" style="position:relative;">
        <div ui-view="" class="page-fade">
          <!--checkout/service.html should be here-->
        </div>
      </div>

   </div>


</div>
```

and the corresponding states...

```
.state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/:lang',
    views: {

      '@': {
        templateUrl: function(params) {
          return views + params.lang + '/holder.html';
        },
        controller: 'MainController as main'
      }

    },
    params: {
      lang: null
    }
  })

.state('root.checkout', {
    url: '/checkout/:type',
    abstract: true,
    views: {

      '@root': {
        templateUrl: function(params) {
          return views + params.lang + '/checkout/index.html';
        },
        controller: 'CheckoutController as checkout'
      },
      'progress@root.checkout': {
        templateUrl: function(params) {
          return views + params.lang + '/checkout/progress.html';
        }
      }

    },
    params: {
      type: null
    }
  })

.state('root.checkout.delivery', {
    url: '/delivery',
    views: {
      '@root.checkout': {
        templateUrl: function(params) {
          return views + params.lang + '/checkout/delivery.html';
        },
        controller: 'CheckoutDeliveryController as delivery'
      }
    }
  })

.state('root.checkout.delivery.service', {
    url: '/service',
    views: {
      '@root.checkout': {
        templateUrl: function(params) {
          return views + params.lang + '/checkout/service.html';
        },
        controller: 'CheckoutServiceController as service'
      }
    }
  })
```

We have no issues with the 'root.checkout.delivery' state and the 'root.checkout.delivery.service' state works perfectly 99.9% of the time when routing to the state via $state.go('root.checkout.delivery.service') - however, sometimes the service.html doesn't get rendered. There's no console errors and none of the service.html can be found in the dom(when checking via chrome dev tools) and the rest of the app continues fine.

We're really struggling with where to look next. We've ruled out any javascript issues in the service controller. Nothing appears to break, the service html just isn't rendered occassionaly. And the issues appears across multiple versions of chrome atleast. We are using a very similar nested state structure across our entire app without this issue.

Has anyone encountered any similar issues? Could any invalid html in the service.html or parent states cause anything like this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you wrapping your html with `<div ui-view> ... </div>`?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I'm not. Apologies, I was trying to show how the structure all comes together - I've clarified the question to be clearer.

Comment: what version of ui-router?

Comment: @ChrisT ui-router v0.3.0